# How can I configure treesitter to use a different compiler and avoid crashing when opening bash files in LunarVim?

Tags: treesitter, lunarvim

I am trying to run LunarVim on a server which is quite old. The installed gcc on the system is causing issues because it is older (GCC 4.9), specifically with treesitter. I don't have admin access on the system to update it. I compiled a newer version of gcc which I can use locally, how do I get treesitter to always use that one?

To get past the treesitter install step I added the below line to my config.lua file

```lua
require 'nvim-treesitter.install'.compilers = { "/path/to/new/gcc" }
```

This caused treesitter to work fine until I try to open a bash file when the program crashes with an error message looking for a shared object file the older gcc does not have.

I am looking for a way to get everything related to LunarVim and treesitter to always use the new gcc install in my home drive. I am also okay with disabling treesitter for bash files since that is better than crashing entirely but it is less preferable.